# Can't set self.value from function other than __init__

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I'm making a platformer (just for fun, to learn new concepts) in pygame. I'm trying to make a scrolling background, and I need to reset the x value when it hits a certain point. The code below doesn't work, and pycharm says that 'The statement seems to have no effect'. Can I not change a value of self from any function other than `__init__`? Here is my source:

````py
class background:
    def __init__(self, image_location):
        self.location = pygame.image.load(image_location)

    # defaults V
    class left:
        x = 0 - w/2
        y = 0
    class right:
        x = w/2
        y = 0
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def scroll(self):
        if self.left.x > 0-w:
            self.left.x -= 1
        else:
            self.left.x == w
        if self.right.x > 0-w:
            self.right.x -= 1
        else:
            self.right.x == w
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.location, (self.left.x, self.left.y))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.location, (self.right.x, self.right.y))```
````

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the embedded classes `background.left` and `background.right`?

Comment: The way that you would cause your `background` instance to contain a `.left` is the same way you do cause it to contain a `.location`.

Answer (score 1):

w is not defined and x, y should be a classmethod

The code below will work(Assuming that w is defined)

````py
class left:
    x = 0 - w / 2
    y = 0

class right:
    x = w / 2
    y = 0

class background:
    def __init__(self, image_location):
        self.location = pygame.image.load(image_location)
        self.left = left()
        self.right = right()

    def scroll(self):
        if self.left.x > 0-w:
            self.left.x -= 1
        else:
            self.left.x == w
        if self.right.x > 0-w:
            self.right.x -= 1
        else:
            self.right.x == w
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.location, (self.left.x, self.left.y))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(self.location, (self.right.x, self.right.y))```
````